# Checkbox list - dynamic list C#/XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have 3 tables

**User:**

```
  id
  name
```

**Preference:**

```
  id:
  title:
```

**UserPreferences:**

```
  user_id
  preference_id
```

How to create a view model for hold data and create a form like this?

```
New User

Name
|------------|
|textbox     | 
|------------|

Your Preferences
[ ] Preference1
[ ] Preference2
[ ] Preference3
..
[ ] PreferenceN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe, it should look something like this:

metacode with C#

```
// You can realize INotificationChanged here too if you need
sealed class Preference 
{
  public Preference(string name, bool isSelected)
  {
    Name = name; 
    IsSelected = isSelected;
  }

  public string Name { get; private set; }
  public bool IsSelected { get; set; }  
}

sealed class User : INotificationChanged
{
  private ObservaleCollection<Preference> viewPreferences;

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  public User(PreferenceCollection preferences)
  {
    PreferenceTitle = preferences.Title;
    // put info to collection
  }

  public ObservaleCollection<Preference> Preferences
  {
    get { return preferences; }
  }

  // You can remove set if you don't want to set it directly
  public UserId { get; set; }
  public UserName { get; set; }
  public PreferenceTitle { get; private set; }

  // Use it to update data in view
  protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
  {
      PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
      if (handler != null)
      {
          handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
      }
  }
}
```

it is just a mockup of a model. Of course, you need to add validation, save data logic and to bind properties to xaml form